# PHP Curl Proxy - Is there an error?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,'103.228.152.11');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,'80');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
if($post){
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
}
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$arr = array("\t" => null,"\n" => null,"\r" => null);
return strtr($result,$arr);
```

I was pulling data from a site, but I can not pull it. I am using curl proxy for the first time, is there an error in the above code? Because he does not pull it again.

Comment: "is there an error in the above code?" we who should ask that, trace any errors with your code, this may help : [curl_error](http://php.net/curl_error)

Comment: and as a side note, stop using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option at least when you are trying to debug your curl requests

Comment: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: there is an issue with your proxy server

Comment: How do I find a running proxy server?

Comment: buy one, or for your development google for some -temporary- free proxy servers